# In $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$: why is $(x,y-1)+(x-1,y)=R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have these two ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$: $I=(x,y-1)$ and $J=(x-1,y)$. I would like to show that there exist $i,j$ belonging to $I$ and $J$ respectively such that $i+j=1$, so that $I + J= \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Comment: You mean $x + (-1)(x-1)=1$?

Comment: Isn't an element of I necessarily sum of products of elements of (x) and (y-1)?

Comment: @Dalamar You sound like you are describing $(x)(y-1)$, not $(x, y-1)$.  Completely different.

Comment: No, $I$ contains sums of multiples of $x$ and multiples of $y-1$, i.e. $rx + s (y-1)$.

Comment: I thought for two hours about a problem with the wrong definition in mind. Feels good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $I+J = \{i+j\mid i\in I, j\in J\}$. In the case given, take $i=x$ and $j=(-1)(x-1)=1-x$. Then $i+j=1$.